# How to create script that listens to content changes and touches parent folders all the way up?

Tags: bash, cmd.exe, ntfs

This is my workpace. It is grouped by date to help me orient in it.

[image: workspace]

Some of the folders group other projects by a company, for example. The problem is that file changes in those folders don't propagate to the container folder and even though there are projects that I have worked on recently, the folder will remain buried in history.

I would like to have a solution that will track those changes (1 level deep is sufficient) and touch the parent containers.

> How to write a script that listens to the changes and does what I want?

*I am on windows 10, but I use unxutils in cmd, bash and ubuntu wsl.*

/edit I have just realised that the script doesn't have to listen to the changes but can run automatically every n hours - if that would make things easier.

Comment: In Linux, you can set the modify stamp of a directory to the time stamp of its more recent child with `touch -r $(ls -t | head -1) .` (yes, you can `touch` a directory).

Comment: Excellent, I can totally do that in cmd with UnxUtils or with git for Windows, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @xenoid for the heads up. This is ultimately my solution

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in */; do
    touch $d -r "$d$(ls $d -t | head -1)"
done
```

*Now I just need to figure out how to run it automatically. I'll get back and update this answer...*

Comment: I didn't manage to run it automatically, but it doesn't matter, I just double-click `touch.sh` in the folder and it's updated whenever I feel it's out of sync.